# Open non http url through script tag

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, web, deep-linking

I have the following set of code

```
<body>
  <script>
    function open() {
      var link = document.getElementById("myid").href
      windows.location.href = link;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
      open();
    });
  </script>
  <a id="myid" href=<%="myapp://myapp/"%>>Click here</a>
</body>
```

The expected behavior was 'myapp' app should open automatically when the page is loaded. But the user has to manually click on "Click here" to open the app.

I tried following set of code as well but did not helped,

```
<body>
  <script>
    function open() {
      var link = document.getElementById("myid").href
      window.open(link)
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
      open();
    });
  </script>
  <a id="myid" href=<%="myapp://myapp/"%>>Click here</a>
</body>
```

I think browsers have some kind of security measures to prevent non HTTP navigation through the script.

**NOTE:**

1. I don't have an adblocker neither pop-up block enabled.

Comment: Would it not be simpler to use [meta refresh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta)? `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=<%="myapp://myapp/"%>">` or just `window.location.href = '<%="myapp://myapp/"%>'` without an `a` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in `windows.location.href`, it should be `window`

i've tested your code and the redirect works without the typo, however redirecting like that might be blocked by the browser in several cases.